# How to reload a page when tag cannot be find or content cannot be pulled?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would like to adapt the code below so that the respective URL is refreshed if class "xy" or "href" is not available. The code is part of a webcrawler and sometimes it is facing captchas or errors. Currently, my code just jumps to the next page but I need to refresh page first if it cannot be shown at the first try.

```
                url_pull = url.find('a',class_ = 'xy')
                partial_url = url_pull.get('href')
                pageURL = 'http://xxx'+partial_url
                Url_list.append(pageURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `While True` condition, and `break` if you found a result.

So, something like:

```
while True:
    url_pull = url.find('a', class_='xy')
    partial_url = url_pull.get('href')
    if url_pull or partial_url is not None:
        break
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. I get "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: @bencolo That's something else. You have an indentation error. You're probably mixing tabs and spaces. Choose only one